# Case Assignment Rules on Records in a queue

Tags: apex

Is it possible to have Outlook case records sent to a default queue, pulls them out of the queue and rerun assignment rules and using a role value to assign with a trigger or some sort of workflow?

I know this sounds ridiculous but trying to clean up a complicated mess. Too many rules in SF to configure SFO. Just want Outlook users to have a simple place to send a case, then rerun complicated assignment rules.

Comment: you might want to also post this on https://success.salesforce.com/ as there are many experts on SFO to draw on

Comment: I did post this to the Salesforce site.  The bottom line is that my client has a very complex Assignment rule set for Cases. This makes the set up in the Outlook side panel to create Cases with a specific destination quite laborious and far too complex for the users involved. They could create the case in SF and the Assignment rules would then be in effect but Email to Case from SFO is designed to ignore assignment rules and utilize the side panel. This forces less educated users into evaluating an email and based on that eval, choosing the correct User/Queue from the side panel pick lists.

Comment: i've not worked w/ cases and sfo before but I have written triggers on leads submitted by marketing automation system that invoke a future method to re-execute the lead assignment rules - is that approach an option for you (subsstitute cases for leads)?